# C++ Operator Overloading Conflict

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why I am not getting output. I was expecting fun(Test2) called as output.  As the parameters passed are different for the function so there shouldn't be any conflict.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test2
{
    int y;
};

class Test
{
    int x;
    Test2 t2;
public:
    operator Test2 ()  { return t2; }
    operator int () { return x; }
};

void fun ( int x) { cout << "fun(int) called"; }
void fun ( Test2 t ) { cout << "fun(Test 2) called"; }

int main()
{
    Test t;
    fun(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO, casting operators are one of the most abused parts of the C++ language.  Also, when you write code littered with them, you will not know or forget which function is actually called, and can lead the program down a path of execution that is unexpected.  Even if your code did compile, you weren't even sure which function would be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `fun()` is ambiguous. `t` is of type `Test`, which can be converted to both `Test2` and `int`, hence both `fun` implementations are candidates.

Comment: In short, the caller will have to resolve the ambiguity themselves, for example by calling `static_cast` on `t`